# How to convert openFileDialog.FileNames to FileInfo[]

Tags: c#

I have a `OpenFileDialog` and I want to convert selected file names to a `FileInfo[]` variable.

But I don't know how to convert all the selected files in one line code.

This obviously doesn't work:

```
FileInfo[] files = openFileDialog.FileNames;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LINQ:

```
FileInfo[] files = openFileDialog.FileNames.Select(f => new FileInfo(f)).ToArray();
```

Comment: It's `FileInfo[] files = (FileInfo[]) openFileDialog.FileNames.Select(f => new FileInfo(f));` Thank You

Comment: @AlexJolig No, that will fail, use `ToArray` method instead.

Answer (score 2):

The [`FileInfo` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) offers a [constructor that expects a filename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.fileinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Therefore, to get a `FileInfo` instance for a single filename `string`, simply call that constructor:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(openFileDialog.FileName);
```

In your case, you want to get an array and have several filename strings, therefore you can use the LINQ extension methods from the [`Enumerable` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX):

```
FileInfo[] files = openFileDialog.FileNames.Select(fn => new FileInfo(fn)).ToArray();
```

Note the additional call to [`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736(v=vs.100).ASPX) in the end, as [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).ASPX) will return an [`IEnumerable<FileInfo>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).